# Cross Browser Testing of enterprise applications

Tags: tools, browsers, cross-browser-testing

I'm looking for a cross browser testing solution for an enterprise banking application during the QA phase. Is there a tool out there that mimics the action that the tester takes on one browser and replicates on multiple browsers? The scenarios would be quite complex, with widgets, asynchronous JavaScript, SSO, multi factor authentication, etc. The pages are in HTML/ASPX based on the MVC architecture.

From my quick check of common popular tools I didn't quite understand if those would work for me. I checked [Cross Browser Testing](http://crossbrowsertesting.com), [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/), [Adobe BrowserLab](http://browserlab.adobe.com), etc.

We need this for manual testing for now as we may use QTP for automation.

Comment: If you are limited to manual testing solutions then I would give a +1 for Browsershots.

Comment: How would Selinum help in this situation? If you are doing cross browser testing on an enterpise banking application, it would test the functionally on different browsers, but how would this way check for the common browser issues like text wrapping, alignment issue, overlapping, broken text boxes, etc? Isnt browser compatability testing on an enterprise banking application really a manual process? Also, would any tools work with such an application versus a website?

Comment: Hi GWW, welcome to SQA.  Your input is appreciated but it seems to be a comment about someone else's answer rather than an answer to the question.  You can use the Add Comment button to add comments.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried having a look at Selenium or what is now called Webdriver (Selenium2)?

You can use the Selenium IDE to record your tests on Firefox. However after the tests have been written they can be converted to other languages such as C#. Java. Once that is done its quite easy to get the same test to run on Internet Explorer, Chrome, Mobile browsers, etc.

For more details you can have a look at http://seleniumhq.org/

However to be able to do this I am guessing you will need some programming knowledge.

Comment: I think you omitted part of your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of selenium but I'm looking specifically for a manual testing solution.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.  There are so-called capture/playback tools that purport to record a browser session and play it back for you automatically.  In practice they are unreliable and/or require manual editing.  This is especially true when the scenarios are long, the user interface is asynchronous, and the target spans multiple browser types/versions.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would recommend would be to automate your tests using selenium 2, run them in a grid with multiple clients.then leverage the open source testAPI to build an image comparison tool.

There is an excellent blogpost about  this technique [here](http://trishkhoo.com/2012/04/eliminate-boring-testing-automating-visual-comparison/).